# Avoid circular dependency when using interface in Nestjs/GraphQL

Tags: graphql, nestjs

I was following the code first approach to defining a GraphQL interface in the [Nestjs docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/interfaces).

However, the resolveType() requires that you return a class instance and forces me to import the classes that implements the interface (I have the classes in different files); this creates circular depedencies amongst my classes and the interface files.

Example:

`book.interface.ts:`

```
import { ColoringBook } from './coloring-book.model.ts
import { TextBook } from './textbook.model.ts

@InterfaceType(resolveType(book) {
   if (book.colors) {
      return ColoringBook;
   }
   return Textbook;
})
abstract class Book {
   // class members...
}
```

`coloring-book.model.ts:`

```
import { Book } from './book.interface.ts';

@ObjectType({ implements: Book})
class ColoringBook implements Book {
  // class members...
}
```

`textbook.model.ts:`

```
import { Book } from './book.interface.ts';

@ObjectType({ implements: Book})
class Textbook implements Book {
  // class members...
}
```

I've tried [this](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency) like:

```
resolveType(book) {
    if (book.colors) {
      return forwardRef(() => ColoringBook);
    }
    return forwardRef(() => TextBook);
}
```

but that doesn't help as I still need to import the class and it doesn't actually resolve at runtime.

What would be a best practice way of avoiding this circular dependency short of consolidating everything to one file?

Comment: Can you show more code? I'm not sure where the circular dependency is coming in from what you've described

Comment: @JayMcDoniel I've added an example. In this case, ColoringBook -> Book -> ColoringBook and Textbook -> Book -> Textbook. The code still compiles but does give a circular dependency warning that I would just like to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up following how it was done [here](https://github.com/MichalLytek/type-graphql/blob/v1.1.1/examples/interfaces-inheritance/person/person.interface.ts):

```
@InterfaceType({
  resolveType: value => value.constructor.name,
})
```

I am not sure if this has any side effects underlying but it definitely looks cleaner and doesn't require me to circular import.

Comment: This will not work when the actual constructor is different from the class that supports the GraphQL model. e.g. in my case, the objects are instances of mongoose's `model`. In that case, actual string names (as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/69318797/1541141) is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Building on your answer:

It seems like you can simply pass the class name instead of the JS class, which results in:

`book.interface.js`

```
// no import

@InterfaceType(resolveType(book) {
   if (book.colors) {
      return 'ColoringBook';
   }
   return 'Textbook';
})
abstract class Book {
   // class members...
}
```

In my case, `value.constructor.name` was systematically the Interface name (`Book` instead of `<Specifier>Book`)